# Is it possible to bold a text of a list item until you find a dash in CSS?

Tags: css, zk

I am creating a list dynamically and would like to add some CSS that bold part of the text of the list-items. This would be possible to be delivered by bolding the text until you find a dash `-`.

The output I am aiming for is the above:

**First Title** - first element
**Second Title** - second element

```
<listbox hflex="1" style="text-align:left; border: none;" model="@load(model.validationWarnings)">
    <template name="model">             
        <listitem disabled="true" style="background: #ffff !important;">
            <listcell value="${each}" label="${each}" style="font-size: 12px; color: #E85252;"/>
        </listitem>   
    </template>
</listbox>
```

Comment: it's not possible. You should print two different elements separated by a dash

Comment: If so, if you have a JS solution, it would be really welcomed as well :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better option would be to put two labels in your listcell.
Instead of using `ListModelList<String>` or `List<String>` as model, you can use a pojo with msg1 and msg2 fields for example, or any other type that allow multiple entries per line (Map, Array, etc.)

Assuming Pojo option (`ListModelList<MyPojo>` instead of `ListModelList<String>`):

```
<style>
    .msg1{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
...
<listcell value="${each}">
    <label value="${each.msg1}" sclass="msg1" />
    <label value="${each.msg2}" sclass="msg2" />
</listcell>
```

Comment: you could use style as in your original example, but sclass scales better especially if you render "a lot of rows"
it's not much, but it doesn't cost you anything

Comment: Implemented it this way myself as well! Great solution mate, thanks :)